# sony-smarteyeglass change layout parameters dynamically

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I am trying to change line count and `TextSize` in my text view on `SmartEyeglass` dynamically. I am calling `showLayout()` in my `ControlExtension`  to show the layout on the glasses  and then `sendText()` when my text changes. But I don't know how I  can send layout instructions like `setTextSize` for example. or auto calling `setMovementMethod()` on the `TextView` to auto scroll down.

My only idea for those dynamic layout changes would be to create the whole layout in my `ControlExtension`, edit and render it there and send it as bitmap to the glasses as it changes . But they state in their documentation you shouldn't do it in the new API (4) and use the layout functions instead (`showlayout` and `sendText`)

Has anybody found a way to send dynamic layout information to the glasses?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is the right way to go.  To change the text size or position dynamically you will need to create your layout in code and then call showBitmap() to redraw the layout each time.